# Php multiplication error

Tags: php

I'm Trying to calculate my price in Turkish Lira as USD.

It should be simple like TL * USD But im getting wrong calculate.

```
$connect_web = simplexml_load_file('http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml');
$usd_selling = $connect_web->Currency[0]->BanknoteSelling;


echo $usd_selling*2
//It shows 4. But it should be 5.6726, because $usd_selling gives 2.8363 from the xml.
```

Where im doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting the right USD_SELLING value ?

Comment: show an example row from the xml please. Are you sure decimal separator is a dot and not a comma?

Comment: Yes because when i try to echo usd_selling variable, it works and shows 2.8363

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always need to explicitly cast variables that you've retrieved using SimpleXML, e.g.

```
$usd_selling = (float) $connect_web->Currency[0]->BanknoteSelling;
```

PHP will be treating it as the string-value of a SimpleXMLElement object by default.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is treating the value as a string. You need to specify it as a real/floating point:

```
echo floatval($usd_selling)*2; //or echo (float)$usd_selling*2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `float`, otherwise php will treat it as an `integer`, i.e.:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
$connect_web = simplexml_load_file('http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml');
$usd_selling = (float) $connect_web->Currency[0]->BanknoteSelling;
echo $usd_selling * 2;
//5.6726
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check what you get :)

`$usd_selling` is an object.

```
settype($usd_selling, double);
```

will fix it